# QTableView Long Header String Not Fits

Tags: c++, qt4, qtableview

In Qt 4.6.2 although I make resizeMode Stretch and then resize contents to Columns and to Rows, a header string that is longer than the content of every item in that column does not fit.
Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After you resized your table by the contents you can check the single colums if they are too small for their header. When a column is too small resize the colum. The size of the header text you can get with the QFontMetric class:

```
QTableView tv;
QFontMetrics fontmetric(tv.font());

//...

//for every colum:
int minWidth = fontmetric.width(headertextofcolum);
if (tv.columnWidth(colNr) < minWidth){
    tv.setColumnWidth(colNr,minWidth);
}
```